# How do I join a one-to-many table with results only appended to the smaller table?

Tags: sql, rdbms-agnostic

Basically I have a one-to-many table. I want to append the columns of the larger table to the result set of the smaller table. I will end up with a result set the same size of the smaller table, but again, with the relevant information from the many sided table.

One catch: the many sided table doesn't have a primary key defined, although a composite key could be established (again it isn't there as constraint).

Comment: Which part of the relationship does the larger table contain: the "one" part or the "many" part?

Comment: Could you please post some sample data and the resultset you want to get?

Comment: The larger many table would be larger... I want to do a query which is really more focused on the one sided table, yet I want to pull in some results from the larger detail (bad DB design from awhile ago) without having a result set that is as large as the many sided table. In part, this is kind of like sql optimization but on a much more basic level.

Comment: I wrote a sample table layout in my answer, could you please look at it and say: which resultset the query you want should return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since more than one record in `t_large` may correspond to a record in `t_small`, you need to choose what exactly you want to pick from `t_large`.

This means that you'll either need to aggregate all corresponding records from `t_large` (how?), or select a single record out of many (which?).

```
SELECT  s.*, SUM(l.value)
FROM    t_small s
LEFT JOIN
        t_large l
ON      s.id = l.small
```

or

```
SELECT  s.*, l.*
FROM    t_small s
LEFT JOIN
        t_large l
ON      l.id = 
        (
        SELECT  MIN(id)
        FROM    t_large li
        WHERE   li.small = s.id
        )
```

Now, imagine this table layout:

```
t_small

id     value
--     --
1      Small 1
2      Small 2


t_large

id     small_id  value
--     --        --
1      1         1
2      1         4
3      2         9
4      2         16
```

Could you please post the resultset which you'd like to see as a result of the query?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just an left join on the key?

`select * from small_table s  left join large_table l on s.id = l.small_table_id`

Every record in small_table, but only the relevant rows in large_table.

I'm missing something. Please elaborate or provide scrubbed sample data.

Comment: The many sided table doesn't have a PK, the FK (which is the PK in the smaller, one sided table) isn't unique in the many sided table.. sorry, brb editing.